# MongoDB and pymongo: specify `ignore case` flag for `$in` operator

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to run raw query with MongoDB. Now my `$in` filter in pymongo looks like this:

```
{'category': {'$in': ['fruits', 'vegetables']}}
```

But it has revealed that sometimes category is `Fruits` and filter does not match that value. I cannot fix all `category` data in database because there is every day syncing and there are too many checks already. So, the only way is to improve the filter (it's not only `category` in this filter, by the way).

So I wonder is there any way to ignore case with `$in` operator?

---

To be totally clear, what I have now:

filter:

```
{'category': {'$in': ['fruits', 'vegetables']}}
```

data:

```
{'category': 'fruits'} // match
{'category': 'Fruits'} // does not match
```

---

What I need:

filter:

```
{'category': {'$ignorecase_in': ['fruits', 'vegetables']}}
```

data:

```
{'category': 'fruits'} // match
{'category': 'Fruits'} // match
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `i` flag which will make regex case insensitive .

Like in your example.

```
 {'category': {'$in': [new RegExp('fruits', "i" ) , new RegExp('vegetables', "i")]}}
```

I showed you the way as an example. You can apply the DRY approach to not repeat new Regexp for every elements.

Answer (score 0):

## SHORTLY,

for `pymongo` use `re.compile` with `IGNORECASE` flag:

```py
from re import compile, IGNORECASE

items.find({'category': {
    '$in': [
        compile('fruits', flags=IGNORECASE),
        compile('vegetables', flags=IGNORECASE)
    ]
}})
```

---

#### IN DETAILS,

@me-on1's approach is correct.

[`$in` documentation says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the--in-operator-with-a-regular-expression) that `$regex` operator cannot be used inside `$in` (otherwise you'll get `cannot nest $ under $in` exception):

> The $in operator can specify matching values using regular expressions
> of the form /pattern/. You cannot use $regex operator expressions
> inside an $in.
>
> Consider the following example:
>
> db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ /^be/, /^st/ ] } } )

So if I'm allowed to use regular expressions inside `$in` the real question is how to do it in python? Because python does not support /pattern/ form.

Then, I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867389/pymongo-in-regex) and similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622623/7744106) for python.

So all I had left was to specify ignore case flag:

```py
from re import compile, IGNORECASE

items.find({'category': {
    '$in': [
        compile('fruits', flags=IGNORECASE),
        compile('vegetables', flags=IGNORECASE)
    ]
}})
```